# C#, .NET, Check for null in function which converts request to string

Tags: c#, .net, exception, null

I have a function which takes a request and converts it to a string:

```
private string CreateEmailData(Models.V2.RequestPaymentModel data)
{
   var emailRequest = new ApiRequest<RequestPaymentEmailModel>
   {
      Id = id,
      DateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
      Data = new Utils.EmailRequest.RequestPaymentEmailModel
      {
         LanguageCode = data.LanguageCode,
         DeviceID = data.DeviceId,
         CoreSystem = data.CoreSystem,
         Transaction = new Utils.EmailRequest.TransactionEmail()
         {
            Country = data.CountryCode,
            TransactionType = data.Transaction.Type,
            Amount = data.Transaction.Amount,
            Currency = data.Transaction.Currency,
            Authorization = "",
            Type = data.Transaction.Type,
            Description = data.Transaction.Description,
            PaymentNetwork = data.PaymentNetwork,
            ReferenceId = data.Transaction.ReferenceID,
            CartValue = data.Transaction.CartValue,
            PaymentFrequency = data.Transaction.PaymentFrequency,
            InvoiceNumber = data.Transaction.InvoiceNumber,
            GoodsType = data.Transaction.GoodsType,
            ProductID = data.Transaction.ProductId
         },
         CreditCard = new Utils.EmailRequest.EmailCreditCard()
         {
            Number = data.DataPaymentMethod.CreditCard.Number,
            Month = data.DataPaymentMethod.CreditCard.Month,
            Year = data.DataPaymentMethod.CreditCard.Year,
            FirstName = data.DataPaymentMethod.CreditCard.FirstName,
            LastName = data.DataPaymentMethod.CreditCard.LastName
         },
         PaymentMethod = data.PaymentMethod,
         DataSecurity = data.DataSecurity,
         ExtraParameter = data.DataPaymentMethod.ExtraParameter,
         Buyer = data.DataPaymentMethod.Buyer,
         Payer = data.DataPaymentMethod.Payer,
      }
   }.ToJson();

   return emailRequest;
}
```

But sometimes some values in a request like `Payer` can be null.
How can I check values for null in this function?
Right now if value null it crashes the app and returns:

> $exception    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object."} System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Well, it depends. Where are you getting the unexpected null. What do you want to do when this happens?

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm getting in Buyer, but Buyer not a string. It's collecting more entities in ```EmailBuyer``` ```public EmailBuyer Buyer { get; set; }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to include null checks.  Your problem isn't that it can't be converted into a string.  It's that you're referencing null objects.  What you need to do is replace your code where lines that look like this

```
Payer = data.DataPaymentMethod.Payer
```

are re-written to look like this

```
Payer = data?.DataPaymentMethod?.Payer
```

This way if "data" is null then then Payer is null.  If data.DataPaymentMethod is null then Payer is null.  Finally if data.DataPaymentMethod.Payer is null then Payer is null.  If your version of C# supports this syntax then this is what I would go with.  Else you'll either need to write an ugly turnary or create a method that will handle the null checks.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert a null value to a string

This example means that if *Transaction* is null, then use *empty string* instead

```
TransactionType = data.Transaction?.Type ?? ""
```

This example means that if *CountryCode* is null, then use *empty string* instead

```
Country = data.CountryCode ?? ""
```

The syntax itself is basically an inline if statement, there's more to it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do that with int?

Comment: An `int` can't be null. A nullable int (declared as either `int?` or `Nullable<int>` (they are equivalent)) can be. You can treat those the same way

Comment: @Flydog57 for some reason C# ignoring ``` ?? "" ``` and still returns null on strings